# Take all keys and values in dictionary, put them in list - python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, key

I got a dictionary full of keys and values like this:

```
1:0, 2:3 ,3:0: ,4:3
```

The keys go all the way up to 500++ , but the values are usually from 0 - 15. As you see, keys have often the same value.

I want to make an array or list or whats best for each value , so for 0-15 there will be 16 arrays and then take all the keys and put them in the right array.

So in the example it would be:

```
array 0 [1,3]
array 3 [2,4]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
vals = [[] for _ in range(16)]
for k, v in my_dict.values():
    vals[v].append(k)
```

Comment: Actually I only get int object is not iterable.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {1:0, 2:3 ,3:0, 4:3}
lists = [[k for k,v in d.items() if v == x] for x in sorted(set(d.values()))]
print lists
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3], [2, 4]]
```

Comment: This worked great! But if I want to have a name on each list, independently? Say list1 for all the values that belong to key1

Answer (score 0):

```
a={i:[] for i in range(16)}
for k,v in mydict:
   a[k].append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desire a dictionary? Like this?

```
b = {1:0, 2:3 ,3:0 ,4:3}
a = dict.fromkeys(b.values(), None)
for key, value in b:
    if a[value] is None:
        a[value] = []
    a[value].append(key)
```

This will generate the output as:
    print a
    {0:[1,3], 3:[2,4]}

Please note that if the dictionary b is bigger(even more than 16 items), you are better be off initializing it as

```
a = dict.fromkeys(range(1, 16), None)
```

rather than mentioned earlier.